# 2008 Buick Lucerne Accutrack Error code

Tags: buick, throttle-body, electronic-stability-control, stability

My mother's 2008 Buick Lucerne has an error message for the Accutrack system. We've taken it to the dealer, and they want 500$ to replace the throttle body to repair. We don't want to throw more money at the car, as it is very infrequently used. Can I disable the system, even if it makes the car slightly less stable? ie, could I pull a fuse, cut a cable, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's really not at all clear what the car's issue is or what the proposed repair has to do with what you're saying here.  The Accutrack system is a mystery and I didn't find anything related to Buick.  Could you mean the GM Stabilitrak system?  Regardless of that, I am not clear on how the throttle body is related to that.

Comment: Yea, I'm failing to make a connection with the throttle body and stability controls. Not much related with the two. Never heard the term "Accutrack". If its the "stabilitrack" like jwh80 suggests, if the lights are on, its already disabled. To get the lights off you need to fix it which I don't see how it would be related to the throttle body. More likely the EBCM (electronic brake control module)

Comment: Thanks, @narkeleptk. I am conveying most of this from my father -- so second hand.

I'm betting that it's called Stabilitrak system, and my father has the name wrong in the communications with me. Ok, I'll look into getting a EBCM.

Thanks!